# If $ R $ is a commutative ring with unity, then how do I prove: $ a \neq 0, ~ b \neq 0 \Longrightarrow a \cdot b \neq 0 $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $ R $ is a commutative ring with unity and $ a,b \in R $, then how do I prove that
$$
a \neq 0, ~ b \neq 0 ~~ \Longrightarrow ~~ a \cdot b \neq 0?
$$

Does this also hold for any ring?

Comment: You don’t: it doesn’t. Look at the ring $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$.

Comment: •means multiplication here. I dunno how to write small circle in Latex..

Comment: Another example is $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2)$.

Comment: I assumed that you meant multiplication. For the record, you can get the composition symbol with `\circ`.

Comment: @Katlus Use `\cdot` for multiplication.

Comment: @Brian Do you mean, for any polynomial ring $R[X]$, $\deg f(X) + \deg g(X)$ may not be equal to $\deg f(X)g(X)$, where they are polynomials? What would be the weakest algebraic structure which makes that possible?

Comment: If $R=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, then $(2x)(3x)=0$ in $R[X]$. You need $R$ to be an integral domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It’s not true in general: consider $a=2,b=3$ in the commutative ring $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$, which is unital. Rings of the kind that you want are [integral domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain).